# JQUERY - Bubbling after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

I am trying to append content to a specific div using .ajax() and use the new content in a Jquery Dialog. I believe I'm using .on() correctly, but it seems that DOM isn't being refreshed.

To do the .ajax() call, I'm using the following code (it is successful):

```
$(function () {

    var AjaxCall = function () {

        var $link = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $link.attr("href"),
            type: $link.attr("data-project-method"),
            target: $link.attr("data-project-target"), //a.k.a "#DialogX"
            data: null
        }
        //console.log(options);        
        $.ajax({
            type: options.type,
            url: options.url,
            data: options.data,
            success:function(data){
                var id = "DialogID"
                $('<div id="DialogY"></div>')
                                                    .html(data)
                                                    .appendTo(options.target);
                //$(options.target).replaceWith(data);
            }
        });

        console.log($("#DialogY").html());

        return false;

    };

    $("body").on("click", "a[data-project-ajax='true']", AjaxCall);
});
```

The call is successful, and the content is appended correctly to specified div. I created a `<div id="DialogY"></div>` inside `<div id="DialogX"></div>`.

In the next step I am trying to make a JQuery Dialog with the inserted content + content previously existing in "DialogX", however, the content showed in the Dialog, is the content before the appending was made (only what was already in "DialogX"). It looks like DOM wasn't refreshed, eventhough I used .on() .

I tried to console.log the new DialogX div content, but it is undefined in "dialogY".

I believe that on Jquery documentation it is stated that returning false stops bubbling/propagation, but not returning false will make the ajax call reload all page.

After the ajax call, the content shows on page, but not on Dialog.

The code to create the Dialog (Modal on Bootstrap) is the following:

```
<script>
    //// BOOTSTRAP MODAL ////
    $(function () {
        var content = $("#DialogX").html();

        console.log(content);

        $("body").on("click", ".addDialog", function () {                
            AddDialog("I'm a Dialog", content, function () { });
        });

        function AddDialog(title, content, callback) {
            var $content = content;
            var dlg = new BootstrapDialog({
                title: title, //variable
                message: $content, //variable
                description: "Modal to Edit Platform Variables",
                draggable: true,
                closable: true,
                closeByBackdrop: false, //Click outside Modal don't close it >> working
                closeByKeyboard: false, // esc key Dont't close it >> working
                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DEFAULT, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
                                                    //var types = [
                                                    // BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DEFAULT,  >> BEST
                                                    // BootstrapDialog.TYPE_INFO, 
                                                    // BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY, 
                                                    // BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS, 
                                                    // BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING, 
                                                    // BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER];
                onshown: function (dialog) {
                    var tier = $('.bootstrap-dialog').length - 1;
                    dialog.$modal.prev(".modal-backdrop")
                        .css("z-index", 1030 + tier * 30);
                    dialog.$modal
                        .css("z-index", 1040 + tier * 30);
                },
                buttons: [{
                    label: 'OK',
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-send', // Imagem no botão
                    autospin: true,
                    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                    action: function (dialogRef) {
                        if (callback !== "") { callback(); }
                      //  dialogRef.close(); //autoClose
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            dialogRef.close(); // waites for X seconds to close
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }, {
                    label: 'Close',
                    cssClass: 'btn',
                    action: function (dialogRef) {
                        dialogRef.close();
                    }
                }]
            }).open();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I've spent more days then I am proud with this error. It seems that every thing is right, but it obviously isn´t.

Can someone please point what am I doing wrong? Or what is missing? Probably it is something obvious... But I can't figure out, what it is...

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `on` just means that the click handler will work for newly-added elements. It doesn't really have anything to do with your problem about the dialog having "stale" contents.

You're setting this variable: `var content = $("#DialogX").html();` just once, in your `ready` handler. So, `content` is the HTML contents of the `DialogX` div *from when the page was loaded*, and you never update `content`.

The simplest change would be to push the call to `.html()` into your dialog click handler, so the dialog contents will get "calculated" anew right as you're about to open the dialog:

```
$("body").on("click", ".addDialog", function () {                
    AddDialog("I'm a Dialog", $("#DialogX").html(), function () { });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @John Flatness , your solution worked great... sorry for the trouble.